# Extracting feature points from flow lines and clustering them?

Tags: matlab, tracking, matlab-cvst, opticalflow, vision

I'm trying to make a reliable passenger counting system using matlab, the camera will be fixed and above the door. I a able to get flow lines using Lucas Kanade optical flow, the lines represent the people's motion. I want to:

1. extract from these lines only the end points, if the line is long enough (the lines matrix contains all the points, even say a point on some random part of floor which will not have changed)
2. Cluster these 'good points' and get the centroids of the clustsers, representing people
3. Create bounding boxes of a fixed size on those cluster centers and send them to the multiple object KLT tracking program.

Would anyone happen to show me a good way to extract the points I want from the line matrix? My matlab syntax is atrocious and I'm running out of time to get this done, its for a uni project. Thanks in advance!

```
%example
    videoReader = vision.VideoFileReader('5Converted.avi','ImageColorSpace','Intensity','VideoOutputDataType','uint8');
    converter = vision.ImageDataTypeConverter; 
    opticalFlow = vision.OpticalFlow('ReferenceFrameDelay', 1);
    opticalFlow.OutputValue = 'Horizontal and vertical components in complex form';
    shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape','Lines','BorderColor','Custom', 'CustomBorderColor', 255);
    videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Name','Motion Vector');
    while ~isDone(videoReader)
        frame = step(videoReader);
        im = step(converter, frame);
        of = step(opticalFlow, im);
        [lines, trackedPoints] = getFlowLines(of, 20);
        if ~isempty(lines)   
          out =  step(shapeInserter, im, lines);   
        end
    end
    release(videoPlayer);
    release(videoReader);
```

And this is the GetFLowLines Function (slightly modified version of an example):

```
> function [vel_Lines, allTrackedPoints] = getFlowLines(vel_Values,
> scaleFactor)  %Modified function based on Matlab's
> 'videooptflowlines.m' helper function 
> 
> persistent first_time; persistent X; persistent Y; persistent RV;
> persistent CV; if isempty(first_time)
>     first_time     = 1;
>     %% user may change the following three parameters
>     borderOffset   = 5;
>     decimFactorRow = 5;
>     decimFactorCol = 5;    
>     %%
>     [R C] = size(vel_Values);
>     RV = borderOffset:decimFactorRow:(R-borderOffset);   
>     CV = borderOffset:decimFactorCol:(C-borderOffset);
>     [Y X] = meshgrid(CV,RV); end
> 
> tmp = vel_Values(RV,CV); tmp = tmp.*scaleFactor; vel_Lines = [Y(:)  
> X(:)   Y(:)+real(tmp(:))   X(:)+imag(tmp(:))]; allTrackedPoints =
> [Y(:)+real(tmp(:))   X(:)+imag(tmp(:))];
```

Comment: it's not my area of expertise so I in any case I won't be the one answering your question ... but if you want to increase your chance of someone even trying you'd better include a complete **runable** example (so provide a link to your movie data for example). I suggest you read how to create an [mcve] and then rework your question accordingly.

Comment: If you want to count the number of people who cross the door why are you not using a IR sensor or something more reliable than a camera ?

Comment: using an IR sensor becomes a problem with multiple people too and I dno its just I don't have much more time and I've been using computer vision for the last 6 months so dont want to completely redesign my approach now.